# jQuery multiple objects animation sequence in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, queue, sequence

I need to sequence jQuery animation on different objects in the *for* loop.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#o1').click(function() {

  for (var a=0; a<3; a++){
    console.log('a = ' + a);
         // ... some calculations
    animateCard($('#o1'));
    animateCard($('#o2'));
         // ... some calculations
        }
    });
});

// In reality this function will have object and target inputs
function animateCard(card){ 
    if (card.offset().left == 400) card.animate({left: 0}); // move home
    else card.animate({left: 400});
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="o1" class="card green">Click me</div>
<div id="o2" class="card red"></div>

<div id="p1" class="card gray"></div>
<div id="p2" class="card gray"></div>
```

Here is JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/fu3mte6u/1/

1. I get this:

   - loop is started,
   - object1, object2, .. nth object move all together to theirs positions
   - till they arrive to theirs FIRST destination, ALL iterations are cycled trough (console log shows)

*In JSFiddle example if you click on green square - animation will start. And after one move will stop. If you click green rectangle again it will execute desired animation of second iteration (but ALL loop iterations will be gone again in this one move)*

2. Desired result:

   - iteration one - move object1 to position1, only then move object2 to pos2, then .... nth to nth position
   - iteration two - again move object object1 to some other position, then move object2, then .... nth
     and so on...
     (Do not animate all together, but step by step)

*For JSFiddle example it would be like this - first green rectangle moves right, than red one moves right, than
comes next iteration, and green one comes back to its original position, than red one returns, and on third iteration red will go right after green one.*

As number of iterations, moving objects and their destinations are changing and animation is inserted between calculations I couldn't write callback function() for each animation.
Queue, as I understand works for sequencing animations of one object.

So, maybe You can help to sequence animation of multiple objects in the loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by queuing animations on the document.

Updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('#o1').click(function () {                                    
        for (var a = 1; a <= 3; a++) { //Loop to go through each element
            // ... some calculations
            animateCard($('#o1'));
            // ... even more calculations
            animateCard($('#o2'));
            animateCard($('#o3'));
        }
    });
});

// in reality this function will have object and target inputs
function animateCard(card) {                
        $(document).queue(function () {
                var self = this;
                if (card.offset().left == 400)                  
              card.animate({
                    left: 0
              }, function () { $(self).dequeue(); });
              else
              card.animate({
                left: 400
              }, function () { $(self).dequeue(); }); // move home

            }); 

}
```

Updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fu3mte6u/5/)

Comment: Thanks apokryfos, as I already asked on first reply, what about loop ? Despite all iterations they move just one time. Also first animation in next iteration has to wait for the last one of this loop.

Comment: @AisKrym You're right, I wasn't too happy with it either. Made an update to queue animations on the $(document) queue. It should make `animateCard` work as you'd expect it. Just clarify one thing for me. What's the purpose of the for loop? I assumed it was to go through the divs, though that's wasn't your original code.

Comment: Purpose of the loop in this demo was that you have to make animation happening number of times (iterations), On second iteration boxes goes to some other places (returns to original position in this demo). Now they continue animation if I manually click on green one. But not by new loop iteration

Comment: @AisKrym Should now (hopefully) do what you need it to do. Key point is, you need to queue all your animations on the same queue and then dequeue them as they complete since the animation queue is per element by default.

Comment: Amazing! Thank You!
Now I have what to study further, because at the end I think I'll need not completely wait for previous animation's end, but just some delay from the begining

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) of the animation queue to wait for it to finish

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#o1').click(function() {

     for (var a = 0; a < 3; a++) {

       console.log('a = ' + a);

       // ... some calculations
       animateCard($('#o1'));

       // ... more calculations
       $('#o1').promise().done(function() {
         animateCard($('#o2'));
       })

       // ... even more calculations
     }
   });
 });

  // in reality this function will have object and target inputs
 function animateCard(card) {
   return card.animate({
     left: card.offset().left == 400 ? 0 : 400
   }); // move home
 }
```

```css
.card {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
#o1 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#o2 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
}
#p1 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 400px;
}
#p2 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 400px;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.gray {
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="o1" class="card green">Click me</div>
<div id="o2" class="card red"></div>

<div id="p1" class="card gray"></div>
<div id="p2" class="card gray"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You, but what about loop ? Despite all iterations they move just one time